# Allowing a user to access directory with nginx under spring security application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, nginx

I have a application where running with tomcat 8, I am using spring security, so its impossible to access a file where not in my tomcat 8.

For example, my application with tomcat 8 can open with `http://domain.com`, then I have a directory where located at `/root/image`.

But my tomcat location in `/root/tomcat8/webapp/ROOT.war`.

I tried to use `symbolic link` and open the folder `/root/image` as `allmyimage`
but when I try to open that image with `http://domain.com/allmyimage/nature.jpg`, my application with spring security will handle this one and not allow me to access `/root/image/nature.jpg`.

Then I try to use `nginx`, but I don't know what to configure, and I don't know if `nginx` will resolve my problem.

Any suggestion?